# cannot coerce type 'builtin' to vector of type 'character'

Tags: ggplot2

I can't figure out this error message that I get when I try to plot my data.table:

**Error in as.character(x$label) :
cannot coerce type 'builtin' to vector of type 'character'**

Below is the code:

```
dt <- results[,.(`Image`,`MOUSE`,`Genotype`,`Class`,`Cytoplasm..TRITC.max`,`Cytoplasm..FITC.max`,`Cytoplasm..Cy5.mean`,`Cytoplasm..Cy5.max`)]
dt1<- dt[,. (.N),by=.(`MOUSE`,`Genotype`,`Class`)]
print (dt1)

dt2 <- dt[Genotype %in% c("DKO","MalinKO")]

violin.plot <- ggplot(dt[,.(Genotype,Cytoplasm..Cy5.max)],aes(Genotype, Cytoplasm..Cy5.max, fill=Genotype))+geom_violin(alpha=0.2)+
  labs(y=c) 

print(violin.plot)
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks! P

Comment: Please make a reproducible example. That is data and all necessary library calls to run code.

Comment: The error message arises because in `labs(y=c)` the RHS is the `c(...)` function.